# Is it possible to search tmux scrollback history?

Tags: history, tmux, scrolling

I'm starting to use tmux, and I already love it. But if I could search through scrollback history it would be even better (e.g. like in iTerm2). Is there a way to do it as of now?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When you're in scrollback mode, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to search.  More useful information here: [How can I search within the output buffer of a tmux shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/231002/how-can-i-search-within-the-output-buffer-of-a-tmux-shell)

Comment: Ctrl-S works for emacs bindings.  If your tmux is using vim bindings, enter copy mode and use slash (`/`)

Comment: Warning - this does not handle newlines. e.g if you search for a string, but that string occurs split across multiple lines, you will miss the split results!

Comment: with vim bindings, `/` is to search *down*, but you most like want to search *up* with `?`