# Tmux froze after attaching to session

Tags: linux, tmux

Today logged on to a HPC facility to check on my tmux sessions. Did a tmux ls and it successfully listed all the sessions. But when I tried to attach to a session, it hung! So I opened another ssh session to the HPC facility and ran tmux ls and it hung too! Basically any tmux command now hangs. I was succesfully able to kill the hung commands but am afraid to kill the main tmux process as it may wipe all my 12 sessions. The sessions take a long time to set up. I can however see in the monitoring tools that the processes spawned inside tmux are still running. So anyway I can get tmux to respond back normally without killing it? Would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is hung ? When you connect , what is shown ?

Comment: When I type the command 'tmux ls' and press enter, the ssh session becomes unresponsive even to ctrl+c . It doesnt show any output. I have to open a separate ssh session and kill the 'tmux ls' process.

Comment: OK, you can try `strace tmux ls` and check where it is hanging. In case this itself hangs, you can go to a new SSH session and try `strace -p <TMUX LS PID>` where you have to use the <TMUX LS PID> which is hanging. When you know where & why it is hanging, we can try to resolve that. This might be "PIPE/lock" Issue.

Comment: do you think this answer may be a solution?
https://superuser.com/questions/553330/vim-freezes-inside-tmux/553349#553349